# Finding |z| from $arg(z^{1/3})=\frac{1}{2}arg(z^2+\bar{z}z^{1/3})$

Tags: complex-numbers

If $arg(z^{1/3})=\frac{1}{2}arg(z^2+\bar{z}z^{1/3})$ then I need to find the value of |z| where z is a complex number.

I tried by substituting $z=re^{i \theta}$.I got stuck after that.Can't understand how to proceed from there.Help please!

Comment: But thats not the answer given....

Comment: I was partially wrong and partially correct earlier. If $arg(z)=0$, $|z|$ can be anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $z^2+\overline{z}z^{1/3}=z^{2/3}(z^{4/3}+\overline{z}z^{-1/3})$ so that

$$\begin{align}
\arg(z^{1/3})&=\tfrac{1}{2}\left((\arg(z^{2/3})+\arg(z^{4/3}+\overline{z}z^{-1/3})\right)  \\[2ex]
\implies \arg(z^{1/3})&=\arg(z^{1/3})+\tfrac{1}{2}\arg(z^{4/3}+\overline{z}z^{-1/3})  \\[2ex]
\implies 0 &= \arg(z^{4/3}+\overline{z}z^{-1/3}) &(\text{canceling})  \\[2ex]
\implies 0 &= \arg(z^{4/3}+|z|^2\cdot z^{-4/3})  &(\text{since }z\overline{z}=|z|^2) \\[2ex]
\end{align}$$

In other words, the complex quantity $z^{4/3}+|z|^2\cdot z^{-4/3}$ lies along the (positive) real axis. It should be evident that this requires $|z|=1$.

---

If $\arg(z)=0$ put $z=r,\quad r\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and then $r^{1/3}=\frac{1}{2}\arg(r^2+r^{4/3}) \implies 0=0$, which is an identity for all $r$.

So, an additional solution is: $\arg(z)=0$, for which any $|z|>0$ satisfies the original equation.

Comment: Can this problem be done using euler form of z ? Anyway i like your one !

Comment: Your "clearly evident" is not so evident. If $arg(z)=0$, $|z|$ can be anything.

Comment: @A.S. - that is correct. The solution has been amended.

Comment: $arg(z)\in (-\pi,\pi]$ (principal value), so $3\pi/2$ is excluded.